# Output data to different .txt files

Tags: php, html

I have a html form and use the get method

I want to input the data to shoes_sales.txt if the user select shoes option value, and input  all the rest to clothes_sales.txt.

I'm using the following if statements

```
<?php
header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");

if($_GET['variable1'] == "shoes" || $_GET['variable1'] == "shoes"){
  $handle = fopen("shoes_sales.txt", "a");
  foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  }
  else {
    $handle = fopen("clothes_sales.txt", "a");
    foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
      fwrite($handle, $variable);
      fwrite($handle, "=");
      fwrite($handle, $value);
      fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
      fclose($handle);
      exit;
?>
```

Comment: Look at your code after I formatted it. Do you see the issues?

Comment: Whz are you asking if shoes or shoes?

Comment: `$_GET['variable1'] == "shoes" || $_GET['variable1'] == "shoes"` am i drunk? O.o

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing `}` for your `if` and `else` clauses, and your second `foreach`.

```
<?php
header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");

if($_GET['variable1'] == "shoes" || $_GET['variable1'] == "shoes"){
    $handle = fopen("shoes_sales.txt", "a");
    foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
else {
    $handle = fopen("clothes_sales.txt", "a");
    foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lost of missing brackets and logic issues

Try this

```
<?php
  header("Location: thankforsumbitting.html");

  if ($_GET['variable1'] == "shoes") {
    $handle = fopen("shoes_sales.txt", "a");
  }
  else {
    $handle = fopen("clothes_sales.txt", "a");
  }
  foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable."=".$value."\r\n");
  }
  fclose($handle);
  exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making repeated `fwrite()` calls, why not build your formatted text, then write just once to the end of the txt file with [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)?  This way fewer function calls are made.

Code:

```
$data = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $data .= "{$key}={$value}" . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents(
    $_GET['variable1'] == "shoes" ? 'shoes_sales.txt' : 'clothes_sales.txt',
    $data,
    FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
);
```